# How to change PIXI.Text color in PIXI.js v3

Tags: javascript, text, colors, pixi.js

i'm writing some app using PIXI and I really need to change texts color. In earlier versions there was setStyle method, but in v3 it is deprecated. setting _style.fill field doesn't refresh the text on screen. with images there is a updateSourceImage method but here... nothing. anyone have some idea or already had the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

okay i probably get the anwser myself... i tried to use that deprecated method and there was this hint

> setStyle is now deprecated, please use the style property, e.g :
>   myText.style = style;

too bad, that it isnt in the documentation